# Pass IEnumerable list to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable

In my asp.net MVC 4 project, I'm trying to pass IEnumerable list from view to controller. The problem is that the list receiverd in the action is null. Any help please.

This is part of my code

view :

```
@model IEnumerable<PFEApplication.Models.agent>
<div id="Leader"> 
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNewLeader", "Equipe", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions {
                    UpdateTargetId = "Leader",
                    HttpMethod = "Post",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                    }))
  {
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID_agent)
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.SelectedAgent, item.ID_agent)           

       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nom_agent) 
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prenom_agent)           
        <br />           

      }
      <br />
     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
     } 
     </div>
```

Controller :

```
     public ActionResult AddNewLeader(IEnumerable<agent> ListAgent) 
    {        
            [...]
            if(ListAgent!=null)
            foreach (var ag in ListAgent) {
                if (ag.SelectedAgent != 0) { Id = ag.SelectedAgent; }
            }
            agent agentRemplace = db.agents.Single(a => a.ID_agent == Id);                    
            db.SaveChanges();               

        return PartialView("exitAddNewLeader");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in fact that this expression:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID_agent)
```

and similar as well cannot derive a correct name for the HTML input control, and the resulting request parameters are not parsed by model binder. Usually this is fixed by replacing `foreach` with `for`:

```
@fore (int i=0; i<Model.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ID_agent)
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].SelectedAgent, modelItem[i].ID_agent)           

   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].nom_agent) 
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].prenom_agent)           
    <br />           

}
```

Note that you would need your view to be typed with `IList<>` or an array to allow this behavior.

Comment: there is error when I use "modelItem[i]": Cannot apply indexing with []to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>'

Comment: @Tommy, that is explained in the very bottom of the answer. You need to change the type of your view of IEnumerable to say IList - something that supports indexing